# Why does it take two MapView.getOverlays().remove() calls to remove an Overlay?

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview

When does List.remove() not remove? ...in a `MapView`?

I have an application with a `MapView` and an overlay that extends `Overlay`.  In a particular case in my application (the user searches for something that adds my overlay, then cancels the search, at which point I call the code below that should remove the overlay).

**Code:**

```
Log.e(TAG, "Map View Contains Overlay? " + mMapView.getOverlays().contains(mOverlay));
mMapView.getOverlays().remove(mOverlay);
Log.e(TAG, "Map View Contains Overlay? " + mMapView.getOverlays().contains(mOverlay));
mMapView.getOverlays().remove(mOverlay);
Log.e(TAG, "Map View Contains Overlay? " + mMapView.getOverlays().contains(mOverlay));
```

**Log:**

```
03-07 14:05:43.737: E/SearchActivity(22445): Map View Contains Overlay? true
03-07 14:05:43.737: E/SearchActivity(22445): Map View Contains Overlay? true
03-07 14:05:43.737: E/SearchActivity(22445): Map View Contains Overlay? false
```

**Notes:**

- `mMapView` is an instance of `com.google.android.maps.MapView`
- `mOverlay` is an instance of a custom class I wrote (that doesn't touch `.equals()` or `.hashCode()` and extends `com.google.android.maps.Overlay`

At this point the `mOverlay` is removed, but why did it take two calls to remove?  What am I misunderstanding?

**SOLUTION:**

For whatever reason I had a mental block and assumed the `List` of overlays would enforce that my business logic of having one layout of each type within the list.  Turns out it doesn't.  `MapView`s can have as many instances of the same overlay as you like, including two of the same instance (barring memory concerns), so if you add two of the same instance to the overlays, there are two of the same instance in the `List`.  Requiring two `remove` calls.

Comment: Perhaps you added it twice.

Comment: Wow, could I have been that silly? ...testing...

Comment: Sigh.  @CommonsWare wins again.  Thanks!

Comment: As a bonus, your map probably runs a bit faster now. :-)